# Figures appearing at the end of a chapter instead of in text

Tags: floats

I am writing my thesis at the moment and am having problems with one chapter showing all figures (however tables and tikzpictures are fine) at the end of the chapter rather than in-text. No other chapter is having this issue.

Im not really sure how I can give a minimum working example as I am writing it on sharelatex and there are a lot of different files making up the document. However i input my figures as follows:

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
       \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{MCRT_V_shape}
       \caption{10mm 'V' shaped secondary reflector}
       \label{fig:MCRT_V_shape_10mm}
   \end{figure}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: There are limitations on how large a figure can be for [h] [t] or [b].  You can reset these to be larger.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?s=1|0.0000#39020

Comment: you have used `[h]` which tells latex the figure is not allowed to be placed at the top of the page, the bottom of the page, or on a page just consisting of floats, so typically there is no legal place it can go so it drifts to the `\clearpage` at the next chapter, `[htbp]` or no option at all are more reasonable choices.

Comment: Just following up from this for anyone who comes across it. It appears that one of my figures was too large for latex to fit well into the text with the[h] command. All figures after it in that chapter were pushed down to the bottom with it as a result. To fix this I reduced the figure size and changed it to an [h!] command and it now works fine.